# a basic doubt about definition in graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-graph-theory

Friends, I have a very basic doubt about neighborhood of a vertex. I was going through some pdf and their it was written about **i-th neighbor of v, $v \in V(G)$**.  Can anybody explain me the term *i-th neighbor*. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that we’ll need a bit more context; do you have a link to the PDF?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sir, here is the link www.cs.huji.ac.il/~advtheory/lect07.pdf‎

Comment: Thanks; that makes it possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice this statement in **Definition** $\bf1$: *for each vertex* $v\in G$ *fix an ordering of* $v$’*s neighbors*.

Here that means that if $v\in G$ and $N$ is the set of vertices adjacent to $v$, we number the vertices in $N$, so that $N=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\}$, where $m=|N|$. The $i$-th neighbor of $v$ is then the vertex $v_i\in N$. If $v$ has $3$ neighbors, say $a,b$, and $c$, we could order them in any of $3!=6$ different ways, and each of those ways would produce a slightly different zig-zag product. [This blog post](http://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/cs359g-lecture-17-the-zig-zag-product/) about the zig-zag graph product may be helpful: it has some diagrams as well as some discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the set of vertices with the distance $\le i$ from $v$.

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but it turns out to be wrong in this case.